# Vue JS Nested Routes with Queries

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm new to Vue and have been working on a demo project and I can't seem to understand how routes with query parameters work. I noticed in the documentation that they recommend `router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' }})` which would produce `/register?plan=private`.

Is there a way to do this with nested routes?

I'm trying to achieve this as the URL for the BookAppointment component: `/physicians/?appt_id=12345&npi=123456789`. If there is a better way to do this I'm open to suggestions. Thanks in advance.

**router/index.js**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
   { path: '/physicians/', component: PhysicianLanding,
     children: [
      {
        // PhysicianProfile
        path: 'profile/:url',
        component: PhysicianProfile
      },
      {
        // BookAppointment has 3 different progress steps to get to
        // the confirm page
        path: '',
        query: { appt_id: '12345', npi: '123456789'},
        component: BookAppointment
      }
    ]
   }
 ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
   { path: '/physicians/', component: PhysicianLanding,
     children: [
      {
        // PhysicianProfile
        path: 'profile/:url',
        component: PhysicianProfile
      },
      {
        // BookAppointment has 3 different progress steps to get to
        // the confirm page
        path: '',
        //query: { appt_id: '12345', npi: '123456789'}, // not required here.
        component: BookAppointment
      }
    ]
   }
 ]
})
```

> To go to BookAppointment Component with URL as -> `/physicians/?appt_id=12345&npi=123456789`, you may need to make a button/link in the vue-template with following @click event:

```
<button 
  @click="$router.push({ path: '/physicians/', query: { 
   appt_id: 12345, 
   npi: 123456789
  }})"
>
 GO TO: Book Appointment
</button>
```

OR

```
<button 
 @click="$router.push({ path: '/physicians/?appt_id: 12345&npi: 123456789})"
>
 GO TO: Book Appointment
</button>
```

You can change the query values, still, *BookAppointment* component will be rendered.

Eg. `/physicians/?appt_id: 123456&npi: 1234567890` Will also render the *BookAppointment* Component.

You can use the different query value to fetch different data from the database & render it on the same base template.